# How do I remove element using .click and .remove in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfK5a/2/)

and here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<h2>Todo List</h2>
<div id='additem'>
    <input type='text' name='additem'/>
    <button>Add Item</button>
</div>
<div id='todolist'>
    <ol>
    </ol>
   <!-- Add item from "additem" input field -->
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var item = $('input[name=additem]').val();
        $('ol').append('<li>'+ item +' <button id="remove">Remove</button></li>');
    });
    $("#remove").click(function(){
       $(this).parent('li').remove();
    });

   });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added elements using event delegation. You can delegate event to *parent* element that is available when you bind event using on or you can use `document` otherwise.

```
$(document).on("click", "#remove", function(){
   $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

#### delegated events

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thank you. This explains exactly what I didn't understand. Codecadamy can teach me how to bait a hook. But it can't really teach me to fish.

Answer (score 1):

As you are creating remove button dynamically - You need to delegate click event like this

```
$("#todolist").on("click", "#remove", function(){
   $(this).parent('li').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/rfK5a/6/

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I have doubt in the remove, if we have more then 3-4 parents class then how can remove work? for example,<div class="parent"> <div class="a"><input type="text"><input type="text"><input type="text"></div><div class="remove"><span>Remove</span></div></div>

Answer (score 1):

You can add live event on the container:

```
$('#todolist').on('click', 'button', function(){
  $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/rfK5a/4/

Comment: But it is not delete clicked item its delete last appended item.

Comment: this in this context refers to the button that was clicked and it goes up in the tree until it finds li element.

Answer (score 1):

Well here it is http://jsfiddle.net/rfK5a/7/

You will need below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var item = $('input[name=additem]').val();
        $('ol').append('<li>'+ item +' <button class="remove">Remove</button></li>');
    });
    $("#todolist").on("click",".remove",function(){
       $(this).parent('li').remove();
    });

   });
```

I will suggest to use `remove class` instead of remove id as you will be having multiple remove Buttons. and ideally we should not have more than one element with one id.

Answer (score 1):

Since live() has been removed since jQuery 1.9 and you are using jQuery 2.0 in your jsfiddle the simple answer is to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/%20on%28%29) as others have pointed out.  http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed

I would also change the id to a class on the 'remove' button since there can be many of these. Also change parent() to closest() so if your markup changes slightly your code will still work.

http://jsfiddle.net/rfK5a/10/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    var item = $('input[name=additem]').val();
    $('ol').append('<li>'+ item +' <button class="remove-btn">Remove</button></li>');
  });
  $('#todolist').on('click', '.remove-btn', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation this makes perfect sense.